# How can I change background image file dynamically depending on device in a FireMonkey Mobile Application?

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey

How can I change **background image file dynamically** depending on device's **screen resolution** in a **FireMonkey Mobile Application** (iOS, android)? There is an option in IDE for icons and splash screens but not for the background image. [image: ide icon/splash screen select]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using a TImage to display the image, use the MultiResBitmap property and it's associated editor: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/MultiResBitmap_Editor